# Getting align in Latex to work for Phonological Rules

Tags: alignment, latex

First time questioner and extremely new LaTeX user here. I'm trying to get equations to line up according to the arrow symbol used in my linear rules for a Phonology paper.

```
\begin{align}
    \text{/b'al/} &\arrow\ \text{[b\super{j}\textipa{A}l]}\\
    \text{/luna/} &\arrow\ \text{[wu.n\textipa{A}]}\\
\end{align}
```

For this I made \newcommand{\arrow}[0]{$\rightarrow$} to avoivd swapping in and out of mathmode.The format I'm trying to get is that it would have the first and second lines match up according to the arrow. However, I keep getting a "Missing } inserted.  } l.38 \end{align}". 
Sorry for the possibly dumb question, but can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `\arrow` in both math and text mode, then you can use

```
\newcommand{\arrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
```

which will ensure it be typeset in math-mode, regardless of the context. Note that [there are some problems with using `\ensuremath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/5764). However, they may not pertain to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the align environment already defines math mode, and because your `\arrow` definition includes the math mode delimiters it breaks the whole thing. You just have to write `\rightarrow` without the `$ ... $` around it.

If you want, define another command `\marrow[0]{\rightarrow}` to use within math mode.

If this answered your question, please mark it as such so that others know that it worked for you.